# Configuring Mackie midi contoller with FL Studio

Tags: audio, midi, digital-audio, fl-studio

I am turning here with the hope that someone can help me!

I just bought a Mackie Universal Control mixer off the internet. The mixer connects to my computer via my mAudio Delta 1010LT MIDI interface. I am having trouble getting the mixer to completely communicate with FL Studio.

The midi out is talking to the mixer. but the mixer is not sending a signal back.

Are there any settings, other than setting the output midi port to 102, that need to be entered in FL Studio? Everywhere I looked it said the mixer should automatically talk back to FL Studio.

Comment: Try using your midi controller with LMMS (its free) just to rule out the question of your card being bad..

Comment: I found the problem, turns out it was bad cable.